# What is the relationship between a complex manifold being Kähler, projective, nonprojective, and nonKähler?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I was wondering if this implication is true. I read a few places that
$$\text{nonprojective} \Longrightarrow \text{nonKähler}$$
but I think I maybe have misunderstood. Equivalently, this is of course asking if $$\text{Kähler} \Longrightarrow \text{projective ?}$$

Comment: The two implications you mention are  equivalent for reasons 100% independent of geometry...

Comment: My question was to verify if the first implication was even true, since I read places that the second implication was not true. It was just to clarify misconceptions on geometry...not logic.

Comment: Your question, as it is stated, literally asks if the first implication implies the second. You could probably rephrase it to make it match better with your intention!

Comment: There... revised and done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both of these implications are incorrect.

As $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is Kähler and complex submanifolds of Kähler manifolds are Kähler, all projective manifolds are Kähler. The converse however is not true. That is, there exist Kähler manifolds which are not projective. For example, all two (complex) dimensional tori $\mathbb{C}^2/\Lambda$ are Kähler, but many of them are not projective. In order to be projective, the lattice must satisfy the so-called Riemann conditions (see Griffiths & Harris, Chapter 2, Section 6).

In summary, projective implies Kähler. Taking the contrapositive, we see that non-Kähler implies non-projective.

Comment: Do you mean Kaehler does not imply projective, in the last line?

Comment: To round this out: the [Kodaira embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_embedding_theorem) gives pleasant equivalent conditions to a Kahler manifold being projective.

Answer (score 2):

I give the Campana-Moishezon criterion here which is less known.

**Definition**: A complex manifold $X$ is algebraically connected if for any general pair of points $x, y \in X,$
there exists a proper, connected and not necessarily irreducible curve in $X$ containing $x$ and $y$.

**Campana-Moishezon criterion**: A compact complex manifold is projective if and only if it is Kähler and algebraically connected.

Note that by another result from Campana et al,

A compact hyper- Kahler manifold $X$ is projective if and only if the Néron-Severi group $NS(X)$ is hyperbolic, I.e., negative semi definite but not negative definite with respect to Beauville-Bogomolov-Fujiki's form

[F. Campana. Coréduction algébrique d’un espace analytique faiblement kählérien compact. Invent. Math., 63(2):187–223, 1981.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01393876?LI=true)

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1292940689